# How can I Use JDBC Request/Debug Sampler results match with HTTP Response in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, database

How do I use JDBC Request/Debug Sampler results match with HTTP Response in JMeter using response assertions?

Can you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General recommendation: there are `Variable names` and `Result variable name` fields under [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler:

[image: JMeter JDBC Variable Names]

Using them you can get "interesting" parts of the JDBC response (or whole response) stored into [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn how to work with the JDBC test elements results.

The variable(s) from the JDBC request can be used in the [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion), i.e. you can check if the response of the HTTP Request sampler contains the reqired value or not.